# to show orthogonality of two vectors and their cross product

Tags: real-analysis

I have  two vectors in cartesian form
a=a1 i+a2 j+a3 k and b=b1 i+b2 j+b3 k 
so how do I show that(a x b) is orthogonal to both a and b??

Answer (score 0):

By definition, of course:

$$\vec a\times \vec b=\begin{vmatrix}i&j&k\\a_1&a_2&a_3\\b_1&b_2&b_3\end{vmatrix}=(a_2b_3-a_3b_2)i+(a_3b_1-a_1b_3)j+(a_1b_2-a_2b_1)k\implies$$

$$\vec a\cdot(\vec a\times \vec b)=\color{green}{a_1a_2b_3}-\color{red}{a_1a_3b_2}+a_2a_3b_1-\color{green}{a_1a_2b_3}+\color{red}{a_1a_3b_2}-a_2a_3b_1=0$$

and something similar with $\;\vec b\;$